# Search if ID is on an array in another collection in mongo with mongoose and angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb

So, I have a collection called users where I store the user data like password, username and so on, and then I have another collection called couples where I store inside an array of the users who are in that couple.

In the angular page I want to check if the current user logged in has a couple, so I search for its ID in the couples collection like this:

```
$scope.couples = Couples.query({
    members: $scope.authentication.user._id 
});
```

This return the couple info if the user ID is found in a couple in the couples collection.

The problem is that I get in my scope an array and I can't figure it out how to access the data inside that array (inside the array is the object with the couple information).

So in the $scope.couple if I print the value I get everything in console, but $scope.couple[0].members fails or $scope.couple.members fails.

If a go to the network usage I see a call to couples that returns the info in a json, but I can't understand why is an array in my scope.

Thanks

Comment: Use the debugger in the browser developer tools, add a breakpoint and inspect the array. Alternatively use console.debug($scope.couples) to write to the console the array.

Comment: In the html I can access the value binding like `<p data-ng-bind="couples[0].members[1]"></p>` but in the js I can access the value

Comment: How are you trying to access the value?

Comment: with $scope.couples[0].members[1] I get $scope.couples[0] undefined

Comment: But at what point are you trying to access it. Is Couples.Query async?

Comment: Just after the query function. I really don't know if it is async

Comment: Is Couples a service/factory? If so can you post the code for that?

Comment: Finally I did it with another approach, I've created a new route in the api to make the request and resolve with the json I needed and ended up being cleaner. Thanks though